# jQuery: How to hide Elements, when reveal another

Tags: jquery

sorry in advance, I am a total newby struggling with jQuery.

I'm planning to create a gallery like shown in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lyrus/km6guw7n/8/). so there are several buttons which reveal extra content, when clicked on. This is, what I ve accomplished so far.

Now there still three things missing:

1. I didn't manage to hide again the Extra content, when clicking another button
2. It would be great if there is a way to scroll automatically to the revealed extra content when opened and back to the button, when closed again
3. How would you create a close button inside the revealed content? Would be nice, if it scrolled back to the button.

I would be very grateful, if someone could help me out!
Thanks in advance!

```js
jQuery(function($) {
             var revealButtons = {
                '.rv_button_1': '.rv_element_1',
                '.rv_button_2': '.rv_element_2',
                '.rv_button_3': '.rv_element_3',
                '.rv_button_4': '.rv_element_4',
                '.rv_button_5': '.rv_element_5',
                '.rv_button_6': '.rv_element_6',
                '.rv_button_7': '.rv_element_7',
                '.rv_button_8': '.rv_element_8',
                '.rv_button_9': '.rv_element_9'

  };
  $.each(revealButtons, function(revealButton, revealElement) {
    $(revealButton).click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(revealElement).slideToggle();
      $(revealButton).toggleClass('rv_button_opened rv_button_closed');
    });
  });

});
```

```css
.flex-container {

display: flex;
-webkit-flex-direction: row;
-ms-flex-direction: row;
flex-direction: row;
-webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
-ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-wrap: wrap;
-webkit-justify-content: center;
-ms-flex-pack: center;
justify-content: center;
-webkit-align-content: center;
-ms-flex-line-pack: center;
align-content: center;
-webkit-align-items: center;
-ms-flex-align: center;
align-items: center;
}

.flex-item1 {
display: flex;
background: grey;
text-align: center;
border: black 5px solid;

margin: 20px;
width: 384px;
max-width: 512px;
height: 400px;
}

.flex-item2 {
display: flex;
background: rgb(177, 29, 29);
text-align: center;
margin: 20px;
border: black 5px solid;
width: 512px;
height: 400px;
}

.flex-item3 {
display: flex;
text-align: center;
background: rgb(160, 151, 238);
margin: 20px;
width: 250px;
height: 400px;
}

.flex-item2block {
background: rgb(238, 151, 212);
display: block;
text-align: center;
position: relative;
display: none;
width: 100vw;

height: 50vh;
}

.flex-item3block {
background: rgb(60, 62, 218);
display: block;
text-align: center;
position: relative;
display: none;
width: 100vw;

height: 50vh;
}

.btn {
position: relative;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0);
color: black;
font-size: 16px;
padding: 12px 24px;
border: none;
cursor: pointer;
border-radius: 5px;
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
        <div class="flex-container">
      
      
        <div class="flex-item2">
            <button class="rv_button_1 rv_button_closed btn" onclick="myFunction()">Click Me</button>
          </div>
          <div class="rv_element rv_element_1 flex-item2block">grid-item2block</div>
      
  <div class="flex-item1">
            <button class="rv_button_2 rv_button_closed btn" onclick="myFunction()">Click Me</button>
          </div>
          <div class="rv_element rv_element_2 flex-item2block">grid-item2block</div>
      
      <div class="flex-item3">
            <button class="rv_button_3 rv_button_closed btn" onclick="myFunction()">Click Me</button>
          </div>
          <div class="rv_element rv_element_3 flex-item2block">grid-item2block</div>
      
          <div class="flex-item2">
            <button class="rv_button_4 rv_button_closed btn" onclick="myFunction()">Click Me</button>
          </div>
          <div class="rv_element rv_element_4 flex-item2block">grid-item2block</div>
        
         <div class="flex-item2">
            <button class="rv_button_5 rv_button_closed btn" onclick="myFunction()">Click Me</button>
          </div>
          <div class="rv_element rv_element_5 flex-item2block">grid-item2block</div>
        
       <div class="flex-item1">
            <button class="rv_button_6 rv_button_closed btn" onclick="myFunction()">Click Me</button>
          </div>
          <div class="rv_element rv_element_6 flex-item2block">grid-item2block</div>
                


          <div class="flex-item3">
            <button class="rv_button_7 rv_button_closed btn" onclick="myFunction()">Click Me</button>
          </div>
          <div class="rv_element rv_element_7 flex-item3block">grid-item3block</div>
      
      
       <div class="flex-item2">
            <button class="rv_button_8 rv_button_closed btn" onclick="myFunction()">Click Me</button>
          </div>
          <div class="rv_element rv_element_8 flex-item2block">grid-item2block</div>
        
      
        </div>
      </section>
```

Comment: Inside of your `click` function, iterate over the list of elements `for (let button in revealButtons)`. On each iteration, compare name or class of each button with the selected one. If they match, add style to show it or style to hide otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the HTML so that the jQuery function is fired on any click of your "button" and "extra content" elements. First, the jQuery function parses out the number included in your class names. Next, we identify the number of "btn" classes on the page. I then iterated over this list. When the number in the list matches the number within the class, of the HTML element, that was clicked we open the corresponding "extra content" via slideToggle(), toggle the class between "rv_button_opened" and "rv_button_closed" and lastly check to see if the element clicked was a button or the extra content. If the class name clicked included "element" we scroll to the button, and vice versa. If the number in the list does not match the number within the class that was clicked we close the "extra content" by identifying any of these elements where the styling "display" is not "none". Lastly we remove the "rv_button_opened" class from these elements.

For your #3, the entire div acts as the button. You will need to style it in a way of your choosing.

HTML:

```
<section>
<div class="flex-container">


    <div class="flex-item2">
        <button class="rv_button_1 rv_button_closed btn" onclick="myFunction(this)">Click Me</button>
    </div>
    <div class="rv_element rv_element_1 flex-item2block" onclick="myFunction(this)">grid-item2block</div>

    <div class="flex-item1">
        <button class="rv_button_2 rv_button_closed btn" onclick="myFunction(this)">Click Me</button>
    </div>
    <div class="rv_element rv_element_2 flex-item2block" onclick="myFunction(this)">grid-item2block</div>

    <div class="flex-item3">
        <button class="rv_button_3 rv_button_closed btn" onclick="myFunction(this)">Click Me</button>
    </div>
    <div class="rv_element rv_element_3 flex-item2block" onclick="myFunction(this)">grid-item2block</div>

    <div class="flex-item2">
        <button class="rv_button_4 rv_button_closed btn" onclick="myFunction(this)">Click Me</button>
    </div>
    <div class="rv_element rv_element_4 flex-item2block" onclick="myFunction(this)">grid-item2block</div>

    <div class="flex-item2">
        <button class="rv_button_5 rv_button_closed btn" onclick="myFunction(this)">Click Me</button>
    </div>
    <div class="rv_element rv_element_5 flex-item2block" onclick="myFunction(this)">grid-item2block</div>

    <div class="flex-item1">
        <button class="rv_button_6 rv_button_closed btn" onclick="myFunction(this)">Click Me</button>
    </div>
    <div class="rv_element rv_element_6 flex-item2block" onclick="myFunction(this)">grid-item2block</div>



    <div class="flex-item3">
        <button class="rv_button_7 rv_button_closed btn" onclick="myFunction(this)">Click Me</button>
    </div>
    <div class="rv_element rv_element_7 flex-item3block" onclick="myFunction(this)">grid-item3block</div>


    <div class="flex-item2">
        <button class="rv_button_8 rv_button_closed btn" onclick="myFunction(this)">Click Me</button>
    </div>
    <div class="rv_element rv_element_8 flex-item2block" onclick="myFunction(this)">grid-item2block</div>


</div>
</section>
```

jQuery:

```
function myFunction(button) {
//get the numerical value of the button selected (parse it to an int)
var buttonID = parseInt(button.className.match(/\d+/));
//get the number of btn classes
var buttonCounter = $('.btn').length;
//iterate through each of the button classes
for (let i = 1; i <= buttonCounter; i++) {
    //matches the button selected to the element class
    if (i === buttonID) {
        $('.rv_element_' + i).slideToggle();
        $('.rv_button_' + i).toggleClass('rv_button_opened rv_button_closed');
        //if the element clicked has a class name that contains "element" scroll to the button, else scroll to the extra content
        if (button.className.indexOf("element") >= 0) {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(".rv_button_" + buttonID).offset().top
            }, 1000);
        }
        else {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(".rv_element_" + buttonID).offset().top
            }, 1000);
        }
    }
    else {
        //hide all of the open elements
        if ($('.rv_element_' + i).css('display') != 'none') {
            $('.rv_element_' + i).slideToggle();
        }
        //remove the open class name
        $('.rv_button_' + i).removeClass('rv_button_opened');
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Hey cpyro, thanks a lot for your fast answer! Somehow I still struggle to implement your code into my jsfiddle. Sorry, I m really a noob right now. But what do I miss to make the jsfiddle work? By the way really thanks alot for your help!

Comment: I updated my jQuery to .length in place of .size(). Size is no longer supported in the latest versions of jQuery. This code should now work in your jsfiddle.

Comment: perfect, now it works like a charm! there is only one issue left: when an extra content is already opened and I click on another button above the opened extra content it works perfectly(scrolling stops at extra content), but if I choose a button beneath the extra content, the scrolling goes to far, so I have to scroll up again to see the revealed extra content: https://jsfiddle.net/lyrus/km6guw7n/27/

Comment: my guess for that behavior is, that first the new extra content is revealed and secondly the older extra content is closed. so if I choose a button above the extra content, the closing of the old extra content is not affecting the scroll action, but if I choose a button beneath, the closing action of the older extra content causes an extra jump so the scroll does not work correctly anymore.